# using string how to get image tag in html in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am making a project in C#.net in which i have to get the source code of a webpage and identify some specific tags.

For example i have to find all the

```
           <img>
```

tag in the code. and i have to store it in a variable.

i succeeded in my first step by getting source code of a web page by my c#.net application.
I have no ideas how to get a tag and store its position in a variable?

Give me a sugesstion

Answer (score 3):

To parse HTML use a dedicated library such as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), but [avoid using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Here is [an example on extracting links from a snippet of HTML](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/easily-extracting-links-from-snippet-of.html), you can adapt it to get the img tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use HtmlAgitityPack for this work, it's very flexible with raw html markup to get tagged content, e.g. :

```
 HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
 htmlDocument.LoadHtml("<html><head></head><body><div><img /><div><img /><img/></div></div><img/></body></html>");

 var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
 // 4 nodes found
 foreach (var node in nodes)
 {
     // do stuff
 }
```